# List values of a column present in a dataset with all values of another column

Tags: r

Weird title, so here's my situation: I'm working with longitudinal data, and would like to list all respondents who have taken all available surveys. For example consider this data:

```
respondent <- c(rep(1, 3), 2, rep(3, 3), rep(4, 2))
survey <- c(1:3, 1, 1:3, 2:3)
survey.respondent <- data.table(respondent, survey)
#    respondent  survey
# 1:          1       1
# 2:          1       2
# 3:          1       3
# 4:          2       1
# 5:          3       1
# 6:          3       2
# 7:          3       3
# 8:          4       2
# 9:          4       3
```

In this case, I'd like to select respondents 1 and 3, as they were the two present in surveys 1, 2, and 3. For a finite number of surveys, a loop could suffice, but I'd like this to work for an arbitrary number of surveys.

So ideally I'd have a function like

```
f(col1, col2) { ... }
f(respondent, survey)  # Would return c(1, 3) in this case
# Or alternatively
f(dt, col1, col2) { ... }  # Presumably data.table would work best
f(survey.respondent, "respondent", "survey")  # c(1, 3)
```

Comment: It may not be that hard to wrap the below solutions in a function

Comment: For sure - I'm realizing I may need to do it on two variables, so will try out + microbenchmark your and @Colonel Beauvel's answers soon and mark the fastest. Upvoted both - thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Sure, I used `data.table` approach as you already have that object. If you are benchmarking, then instead of `.SD` ,use `.I` and extract the `V1` column

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 res <- survey.respondent[, .SD[all(unique(survey.respondent$survey) %in% 
                     unique(survey))], by = respondent]
 res
 #   respondent survey
 #1:          1      1
 #2:          1      2
 #3:          1      3
 #4:          3      1
 #5:          3      2
 #6:          3      3

 unique(res$respondent)
 #[1] 1 3
```

Or a faster approach would be using `.I`

```
 res <- survey.respondent[survey.respondent[,
       .I[all(unique(survey.respondent$survey) %in% 
           unique(survey))], by = respondent]$V1]
```

Or you could use `table`

```
  indx <- !rowSums(!table(survey.respondent))
  names(indx)[indx]
  #[1] "1" "3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (I just rename `survey.respondent` to `df` since it is a very long name..):

```
df = survey.respondent

Reduce(intersect, lapply(unique(df$survey), function(u) df[survey==u,]$respondent))
#[1] 1 3
```